# Return the only element in the hash table in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

I am working on a problem as:

```
In a non-empty array of integers, every number appears twice except for one, find that single number.
```

I tried to work it out by the hash table:

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, array):
        hash = {}
        for i in array:
            if i not in hash:
                hash[i] = 0
            hash[i] += 1
            if hash[i] == 2:
                del hash[i]
        return hash.keys()


def main():
    print(Solution().singleNumber([1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3]))
    print(Solution().singleNumber([7, 9, 7]))


main()
```

returning the result as:

```
dict_keys([4])
dict_keys([9])

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am not sure if there is any way that I can return only the number, e.g. `4` and `9`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `return hash.keys()` do `return hash.popitem()[0]` or `return list(hash.keys())[0]`.

Of course this assumes that there is at least one pair in the hashmap. You can check for this using `len(hash) > 0` before accessing the first element:

```py
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, array):
        hash = {}
        for i in array:
            if i not in hash:
                hash[i] = 0
            hash[i] += 1
            if hash[i] == 2:
                del hash[i]
        return hash.popitem()[0] if len(hash) > 0 else -1  # or throw an error
```

Comment: Yep, that works too. Depends on what OP wants to do if the hashmap is empty

Comment: Indexing of a dictionary view doesn't work. @flakes is right.

Comment: @MichaelButscher oooo I always forget that and it trips me up.

Comment: @MichaelButscher that's true but here we're not indexing a dictionary, but the set of keys of the dictionary. It works - https://repl.it/join/pakzpsgx-azizsonawalla . But yes, I agree that flakes' answer is more concise

Comment: I was wrong, you also can't iter the 'dict_keys' object. You need `next(iter(hash), None)`

Comment: @AzizSonawalla what he's saying is that `hash.keys()[0]` will raise the error: `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Ah ok I see. I edited the answer with a fix.

Comment: @flakes What is the next function?

Comment: @QiangSuper https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/next

Comment: We use the .popitem to pop the element out of the keys. Does [0] mean the key and [1] is for value? Another approach is to transfer the keys into a list and return the first element in the list as the result, right? Thanks for your help, @AzizSonawalla

Comment: Get it. Thank you @AzizSonawalla

Answer (score 1):

One solution that might be simpler is to use the `.count` method.

```
myList = [1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3]

non_repeating_numbers = []

for n in myList:

    if myList.count(n) < 2:

        non_repeating_numbers.append(n)
```

Applied to your code it could look something like this:

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, array):
        
        for n in array:

            if array.count(n) < 2:

                return n


def main():
    print(Solution().singleNumber([1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3]))
    print(Solution().singleNumber([7, 9, 7]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you mean that I need to use the list than the dict/ hash table to count the frequency directly. Do you have an approximate time complexity? Thanks.

Comment: `list` data structures in python have a `.count()` method. This method returns an integer value for the frequency of any list element. So my code iterates through the list and checks the frequency of each element. As soon as it finds the one element that is below a frequency of 2 it returns that number. I believe this way of doing it is faster but I don't have any data to back that up.